# Separate objects that I combined using pathfinder

Tags: shapes, pathfinder

Using pathfinder, I created a "compound shape" (either by just clicking "unite" or using option+click "unite" in the pathfinder panel). Is there a way to "uncombine" this shape later or on a copy of it?

Thanks!
Judy

Answer (score 1):

From the Pathfinder panel menu you can select *Release Compound Shape* which will "uncombine" your shapes back to their original state.

You can also select *Expand Compound Shape* to flatten the result to a single shape.

[image: Pathfinder Panel Menu]

- [**Illustrator Help / Combine Objects Using Compound Shapes**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html#compound_shapes)

Comment: .. but **only** if you Option/Alt-clicked the button (CS4+). If you merely clicked, without Option/Alt the objects are expanded upon the Pathfinder operation (CS4+).

Comment: @Scott you're right of course. This answer assumes you have a *Compound Shape*, regardless of how you got it. If you don't, you're stuck with it :)